# How to store GET requests from REST API calls on Azure SQL or Azure CosmosDB

Tags: sql, azure, api, rest, azure-cosmosdb

I have some temperature loggers which are connected to the web.
I can write GET requests in the Postman app, to receive temperature the latest temperature data in a JSON format.
My goal is to automatically make an API call and store these values in an Azure database, either SQL or CosmosDB.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem are highly appreciated!

Best Regards,
Marco

Comment: This is a bit too open-ended, since this can be achieved using many combinations of tools. Are you looking for something more specific than a tutorial?

Comment: Do you need guidance on services that you could use to achieve what you are looking for? Or do you need help with putting together the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

**NEWEST**

If you are interested, you can learn about ADF.

[Copy data from an HTTP endpoint by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http)

**PRIVIOUS**

At first, I wanted to execute Http request in sql server, return the data and then process it, which can be stored directly. And enable scheduled tasks to be executed regularly.

All the scripts were successfully tested locally, but when executed in Azure DataBase, an error occurred `Could not find stored procedure'sp_OACreate`.

I try to find the reason and find the answer.

[image]

So, you must need to create a new program(webjob or others) to realize your function.You can get data by `HttpClient` (in C#), and store the data by CURD.

**There should be no more trouble-free way.**

And in addition, according to my understanding, similar operations are not supported in cosmosdb.

***My attempt steps:***

1. Create a function in local sql server.

   ```
    -- Enable Ole Automation
    sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
    GO
    RECONFIGURE;
    GO
    sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
    GO
    RECONFIGURE;
    GO
    sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
    GO
    RECONFIGURE;
    GO

    /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fn_GetBlockFromAPI]    Script Date: 8/21/2020 12:07:39 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SendHttpRequest]
    (@testurl NVARCHAR(20))
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @url    VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE @obj    INT;
        DECLARE @hr     INT;
        DECLARE @msg    VARCHAR(8000);  
        DECLARE @json   NVARCHAR(4000); --Cannot use MAX with CLR stored procedures
        SET @url = 'http://www.tianqiapi.com/api?version=v6&appid=16879135&appsecret=ucyKFK6p';--@testurl
        EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @obj OUT  -- Creates an instance of an OLE object
        IF @hr <> 0 BEGIN SET @Msg = 'sp_OACreate WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 failed. Cannot connect to Blockchain.info' GOTO Error END
        EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @Url, false  -- Calls a method of an OLE object.
        IF @hr <> 0 BEGIN SET @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Open failed. Cannot connect to Blockchain.info' GOTO Error END
       EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'SetRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'
        IF @hr <> 0 BEGIN SET @msg = 'sp_OAMethod SetRequestHeader failed. Cannot connect to Blockchain.info' GOTO Error END
        EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, SEND, NULL, ''
        IF @hr <> 0 BEGIN SET @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Send failed. Cannot connect to Blockchain.info' GOTO Error END
        EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'ResponseText', @json OUTPUT
        IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Obj
        EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
        RETURN @json
        Error:
        EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
        RETURN @msg
    END
   ```
2. Then you can query `SELECT [dbo].[fn_SendHttpRequest]('')`.

[image]

After get data, you can insert into your db. You also can use `FOR JSON AUTO` to handle your data. **But it not support in azure sql database**.